# How to get the initial location of a continuous touch in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, multi-touch, uitouch

I'm building my first game in Swift and I want to execute a code block that places sprites at my fingers touch location- only if the touch *started* outside of a certain area of the display. This touch may or may not be continuous, and therefore it may or may not be continuously generating new sprites, so the my logic is in `touchesMoved`. Right now I'm using

```
for touch : AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    ...
```

to grab each touch location. However, this seems to be continuously updated and I'm not sure how to reference one specific touch and its starting point (assuming multiple fingers are down at a time). I looked into `UITouch phase`, specifically `touchEnded`, to see if I could work out some other way of going about my problem, but I can't even figure out how to access the `phase` of a touch using the Apple Docs. (This doesn't seem to work: `touch.phase == UITouchPhase.Ended`

I think that I'm also fundamentally misunderstanding how to handle multiple touch events and how to pass information between them (`touchesBegan`,`touchesMoved`,`touchesEnded`).
I may be missing something obvious, but I'm surprised that the docs did a seemingly-poor job explaining and that there don't seem to be many good answers online regarding this question. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: @Danieboy I've already seen this post- it depicts how to grab a touch location but doesn't address how to find the initial location of a continuous touch. I was also curious if it was possible to pass information between the UITouch responders (or if it was good practice).

Comment: Just preserve it in the did touch began event using a variable

Comment: @knight0fDragon Could you clarify? I don't know if I fully understand- do you mean that I can pass information (like a variable) from each of the responders? If I was passing the location from `touchesBegan` to `touchesMoved` how would I know how to handle it and which touch it was actually referencing?

Comment: `var startingTouches = [UITouch : CGPoint]();`   in touchesBegan:  `startingTouches[touch] = touch.locationInView`......   I am pretty sure the object itself doesn't change addresses at any time in the process,  but if it does, then in your touchesMoved code,  you could always compare the previous location to determine what touch you are on

Comment: @knight0fDragon Thank you for the help, but I feel as though this is still too complicated- I could be off but I would have thought that there would be an easier solution along the lines of `touch.getInitLocation`. Also, any idea how to go about handling touch `phases`??

Comment: Why would that exist?  You want to track the movement of your touch, use gestures.  You are already handleing the touch phases,  that is what touchesBegan,touchesMoved, and touchesEnd are,  the phases of the touch

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question on how to pass a value that belongs to the first touch:
Create a variable in your original class

```
var initialPosition = CGPoint()
```

In the touchesBegan assign the touch position to initialPosition

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        originalPosition = location
    }
}
```

In the touchesMoved you now can use the position of the first touch.